# Nesting simple-html-dom file_get_html($url)

Tags: php, nested, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I am attempting unsuccessfully to nest the use of file_get_html($url) from the simple-html-dom script.

Essentially I am requesting a page that has articles on, these articles are being looped through successfully, I can display the contents of these articles fine, however the image is only visible on the individual article page (once clicked through to that specific article).

Is this possible, why is this methodology not working? Maybe need to specify NEW file_get_html():

```
<?php 
$simplehtmldom = get_template_directory() . "/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
include_once($simplehtmldom);

// INIT FILE_GET_HTML
$articleshtml = file_get_html($articles_url);
$articlesdata = "";
// FIND ARTICLES
foreach($articleshtml->find('.articles') as $articlesdata) :
    $articlecount = 1;
    // FIND INDIVIDUAL ARTICLE
    foreach($articlesdata->find('.article') as $article) :
        // FIND LINK TO PAGE WITH IMAGE FOR ARTICLE
        foreach($article->find('a') as $articleimagelink) :

            // LINK TO HREF
            $articleimage_url = $articleimagelink->href;

            // NESTED FILE_GET_HTML TO GO TOWARDS IMAGE PAGE
            $articleimagehtml = file_get_html($articleimage_url);
            $articleimagedata = "";
            foreach($articleimagehtml->find('.media img') as $articleimagedata) :

                // MAKE USE OF IMAGE I WORKED EXTRA HARD TO FIND

            endforeach;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
endforeach; ?>
```

My question is regarding the possibility of making nested requests of the file_get_html() script so I can search for the image for a specific article on a separate page, then return to the previous file_get_html loop and move on to the next article?

I believe if it was at all possible would need me to set up something like:

```
something = new simplehtmldom;
```

or

```
something = new file_get_html(url);
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `$article->find('a')` returns an array of elements, so when looping over its result, `$articleimage_url` is actually an `a` element. You probably need `file_get_html($articleimage_url->href)` in your second call to `file_get_html`

Comment: Sorry yeah i've cut that out condensing it to a more appropriate discussion. I will update that!

Comment: @Nima edited code

Comment: Are you sure `$articleimage_url` contains absolute URL to article page? Please provide some sample input HTML as well.

Comment: Let me double check, I think you may be on to something here

Comment: @Nima this is not an absolute URL. I will proceed with this knowledge and come back if things are still going pear shaped when we are using an absolute URL! Thanks